# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DataTableContainer)"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using **react-redux-datatable** plugin for table creation.

react-redux-datatable usage: https://sean-ww.github.io/react-redux-datatable/get-started/get-started.html
I have followed the steps given in above docs.

But i am not able to resolve this error. I have included store in Provider Container, but still i am getting the issue.

I am getting error,
**Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DataTableContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a Provider, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(DataTableContainer)".**

I have included the two files index.js and App.js

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import supplierReducer from './store/supplierreducer';
import { DataTableReducer } from 'react-redux-datatable';
import { connect } from 'net';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    supplierReducer,
    DataTableReducer
});

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(logger)
);

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

```
import DataTable from 'react-redux-datatable';

class App extends Component {
render() {
        const apiLocation = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/j59v8';

        const tableSettings = {
            tableID: 'BasicDataTable',
            keyField: 'request_id',
            tableColumns: [
                {
                    title: 'Ref',
                    key: 'request_id',
                },
                {
                    title: 'First Name',
                    key: 'first_name',
                }
            ],
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <DataTable
                    tableSettings={this.tableSettings}
                    apiLocation={this.apiLocation}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        name: state.name,
        address: state.address,
        supplierData: state.supplierData
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSupplierDataListSuccess: (response) => dispatch({
            type: 'SUPPLIER_DATA_SUCCESS',
            response: response
        }),
        onSupplierDataListFailure: () => dispatch({
            type: 'SUPPLIER_DATA_FAILURE'
        })
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I am getting error, **Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DataTableContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a Provider, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(DataTableContainer)".**

Comment: You did not import connect

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am getting the same error and have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

in order to access the store you will need to use a `mapStateToProps` function.  Check out the docs here: [Connect: Extracting Data with mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Comment: I have given the minimal code from the file. If i show the imports it will be very big file. so given only snippet. It does not show any error related to imports.